# Composite API issue

Tags: rest-api, permissions, composite, composite-graph

I am trying to insert record into Member Plan object using composite API.
Note : For simplicity in the below request I removed all other post in coposite API and adding only one with hard coded values

```
string bodyVal='{ "compositeRequest": [  { "method": "POST", "url": "/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/MemberPlan", "referenceId": "refMemberPlan", "body": {"MemberId": "0018b00002Q5fL0AAJ", "PayerId": "0018b00002LHZUYAA5", "MemberNumber": "36478019000",  "Name" : "LIBERTY NETWORK" } }] }';

                req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+getAccessToken.Access_Token__c);
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
         
                req.setEndpoint(envDetails.Base_URL__c+ '/services/data/v55.0/composite/'); 
                req.setMethod('POST'); 
                req.setTimeout(120000);
                req.setBody(bodyval); 
                Http h = new Http(); 
                HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

but getting this error

```
{"compositeResponse":[{"body":[{"message":"entity type cannot be inserted: Member Plan","errorCode":"CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY","fields":[]}],"httpHeaders":{},"httpStatusCode":400,"referenceId":"refMemberPlan"}]}
```

I tried by inserting into direct object as like below

```
MemberPlan plan= new MemberPlan();
plan.MemberId='0018b00002Q5fL0AAJ';
plan.PayerId='0018b00002LHZUYAA5';
plan.MemberNumber='36478019000';
Plan.Name='LIBERTY NETWORK';
insert plan;
```

and it is going through.

I havent didn't do any code change and suddenly getting this issue in PROD but things are working fine in sand box

Comment: Try keeping you API version in sync. Anyways that shouldn't affect this call. I dont see any issue on your code. Check the user permission. The integration user who is making the composite api call.

Comment: @NagendraSingh .As like you said its permission issue

Comment: In that case, I will post this as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When using rest api to insert object. The running user needs to have access to do that operation.

It works in apex because apex runs in `System` mode.

Please check the `permissions` assigned to user with which the API call is being made.